# Jitter buffer calculation in rtp in receiver

Tags: rtp

Can someone tell me how to calculate the buffer size to de-jitter the received packets in RTP? My connection is 1Gbps and the maximum bitrate of ASI is 80Mbps. So how can I calculate the amount of buffer size I need?

Regards
Arash

Answer (score 0):

Two different questions?

https://net7mma.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Rtp/RtpClient.cs

That is my implementation otherwise see the RFC @ https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550